# Get twig variable from a specific route

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a template where the left column is used to display the top sell items.
here's a my master template code:

```
<html><body>
{% block menu %}
{% endblock menu %}    
{% block columnleft %}
   {% include 'TestBundle:Default:top_items.html.twig'%}
{% endblock columnleft %}
{% block body %}
{% endblock body %}
</body></html>
```

my top_items.html.twig code:

```
<table> 
{% for entity in entities %}
<tr>
        <td style="padding: 0px"><img src="{{entity.picture}}"
                    width="60px" height="60px" class="img-rounded"></td>
        <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align: middle">{{entity.name}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Question: 
      Is there any chance to get 'entities' variable from a specific route(localhost/statistics/top_meals) that return an array as response?

I'm asking for this because I have many views, and passing the 'entities' variable using `{%include 'TestBundle:Default:top_items.html.twig' with {'entities': array_var}%}` need to be called in each view.

Thanks

Comment: For this you have to fetch this from controller .Did you try that ?

Comment: I have built a controller that return an array as a response, but didn't manage to get this response from the twig template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are way better of with `render controller` call:

```
<html><body>
{% block menu %}
{% endblock menu %}    
{% block columnleft %}
   {% render(controller('TestBundle:Default:topItems')) %}
{% endblock columnleft %}
{% block body %}
{% endblock body %}
</body></html>
```

and then create the controller:

```
/**
  * @Template()
  */
public function topItems(){
    // SOME LOGIC

    return array(
        'topItems' => $topItems
    )
}
```